GnuCash- Warning: Finance::Quote not installed properly
When I try to edit securities, the following warning appears: 'Finance::Quote not installed properly.' Is there any way to discover what's wrong and fix it?
Thanks in advance.


I reviewed the installation according to https://wiki.gnucash.org/ and attempted to update quotes from outside GnuCash using gnucash-cli.exe --quotes get file://C:/path/to/file.gnucash.

14:27:59 ERROR <gnc.backend.dbi> [error_handler()] DBI error: 19: UNIQUE constraint failed: books.guid
14:27:59 ERROR <gnc.backend.dbi> [GncDbiSqlConnection::execute_nonselect_statement()] Error executing SQL INSERT INTO books(guid,root_account_guid,root_template_guid) VALUES('18375664b997403d9272b42bdb6f3841','7f933e0dcca445f08b4d9c5898a5ad53','10d59324fc264cf3b6dd08a85ccf19aa')
14:27:59 ERROR <gnc.backend.sql> [GncSqlBackend::execute_nonselect_statement()] SQL error: INSERT INTO books(guid,root_account_guid,root_template_guid) VALUES('18375664b997403d9272b42bdb6f3841','7f933e0dcca445f08b4d9c5898a5ad53','10d59324fc264cf3b6dd08a85ccf19aa')
14:27:59 ERROR <qof.engine> [commit_err()] Failed to commit: 17
Price retrieval failed: Finance::Quote check returned error perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LC_ALL = (unset),
(possibly more locale environment variables)
LANG = "en_US"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the system default locale ("Portuguese_Brazil.1252").


It's telling you that part of the software is not present or not configured correctly. Review the installation and configuration instructions. This may require an additional optional  package, or it may be a configuration problem, or a path problem (depending on the operating systems). GnuCash had a fairly active user community, last I looked; they're the ones most likely to be able to help you.

Thank you, @keshlam, for your response.
I reviewed the installation according to https://wiki.gnucash.org/ and attempted to update quotes from outside GnuCash using gnucash-cli.exe --quotes get file://C:/path/to/file.gnucash. However, I still encountered an error. I believe it may be related to the language change. Now I need to discover where to fix it in order to conduct further tests.
I would appreciate it if you or anybody else could assist me with this.

It may be related to [this bug](I just reported).
